# How do I remove the last characters from a string?

Tags: shell, text-processing, variable, cut

I have a variable set with `var='type_cardio_10-11-2017'`. I need to remove the last 10 letters from the variable, and append the remaining value to `var2`.

I tried with the following script, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
var=type_cardio_10-11-2017
var2=${var} | cut -f1 -d "_"
echo ${var2}
```

The output I want is *type_cardio*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To remove everything from after the last `_` in `var` and assign the result to `var2`:

```
var2=${var%_*}
```

The parameter expansion `${parameter%word}` removes the pattern `word` (`_*` in this case) from the end of the value of the given variable.

The POSIX standard calls this a ["Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) parameter expansion.

To remove the last underscore and the 10 characters after it, use

```
var2=${var%_??????????}
```

To remove characters corresponding to a date string such as the one in your example, use

```
var2=${var%_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
```

Which pattern you use depends on how carefully you want to perform the match.

Answer (score 12):

You actually want to remove the trailing *11* characters from the string; here's another way to do it:

```
$ var=type_cardio_10-11-2017
$ var2=${var%???????????}
$ echo "$var2"
type_cardio
```

Answer (score 7):

Another approach in `bash`:

```
echo "${var::-10}"
```

Or in older versions:

```
echo "${var::${#var}-10}" #or
echo "${var: : -10}"
```

Comment: define "older versions"

Answer (score 4):

1) **bash** solution:

```
var1="type_cardio_10-11-2017"
var2=${var1%_*}
```

2) **cut** solution:

```
var1="type_cardio_10-11-2017"
var2=$(cut -d'_' -f1,2 <<<"$var1")
echo "$var2"
```

The output:

```
type_cardio
```

Comment: Thank you sir, But the numeric values will be changing because it is a date string .That is the reason i was using cut .This answer is prefect but can i know how cut can be applied ?

Comment: @SanthoshPogaku, that was not clear from your initial question, you have my update

Comment: Yeah sir, I got what am i looking for . Thank's for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Appending `var` and `var2` is the easy part - you can just join them like `new_var="$var$var2"`. If what you *really* meant to say is you want to *store* cropped `var` into `var2`,then it's just `var2=$(...)` and you can put the commands that other users and my answer  presented here inside the `$()` portion.

The main part is removing those 10 characters. There's number of ways to extract the part you want from `var`:

- `printf` (pretty portable, doesn't rely on specific shell)

  ```
  $ printf "%.11s\n"  "$var"                                                                                                                                                                      
  type_cardio
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  $ var=type_cardio_10-11-2017                                                                                                                                                                    
  $ awk -v awk_var="$var"  'BEGIN{print substr(awk_var,0,length(awk_var)-11)}'                                                                                                                    
  type_cardio
  ```

  or  you can use `printf` trick here as well:

  ```
  $ echo "$var" | awk '{printf "%.11s\n",$0}'                                                                                                                                                     
  type_cardio
  ```
- `egrep`

  ```
  $ echo "$var" | egrep  -o '^.{0,11}'                                                                                                                                                           
  type_cardio
  ```
- `perl`:

  ```
  $ echo "$var" | perl -lne 'print substr($_,0,11)'                                                                                                                                               
  type_cardio
  ```
- `python`:

  ```
  $ python -c 'import sys;print sys.argv[1][0:11] ' "$var"                                                                                                                                        
  type_cardio
  ```